# Django: is it possible to perform queries on a cached QuerySet instead of querying the database?

Tags: python, django, database, caching

I often need to cache results and perform ORM-like operations but with *normal* Python logic because I don't want the database to be hit due to performance issues.

For this very reason I wonder if Django offers a way of performing ORM operations on a cached `QuerySet`, instead of querying the database every single time the *core* query we are using changes slightly.

To visualize what I am saying, let's say we have these different queries:

```
# when evaluated it hits the db
devs = Worker.objects.filter(job__category=JobCategory.DEVELOPER)

# when evaluated it hits the db again
young_devs_salary = devs.filter(dob__gte=datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=24)).values('dob', 'salary')

# it would hit the db again
wellpaid_devs = devs.filter(salary__gte=high_salary_yearly)
```

Note that the first `QuerySet` would be sort of a superset of the rest of the following `QuerySet`s.

What I am after is figuring out a way to tell Django that only the very first query, `devs`, should hit the db, and then cache its results, while the other queries, which use `devs`, should not query the database but the cached `QuerySet` instead.

Is this possible? And if Django does not support this, why? Maybe my scenario is not that common? But somewhat I doubt it, because I stumble upon similar situations daily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Daniel already answered, no you cannot use the querying API that way without finally hitting the database. Now you don't need anything special to filter a queryset's results in pure python - that's mostly standard list filtering using standard python features - but chances here it will actually not improve performances that much, if at all. Avoiding *useless* db hits is fine but that doesn't mean the database is your ennemy, and a decently tuned database with a sane schema will probably outperform pure python list filtering on most cases.

Also and FWIW if the Queryset API did support pure-python filtering it would be implemented as standard list filtering operations etc so it would buy you much, quite on the contrary.

As an example - the pure python version of:

```
young_devs_salary = devs.filter(dob__gte=datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=24)).values('dob', 'salary')
```

would be:

```
target_date = datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=24)
young_devs_salary = [(dev.dob, dev.salary) for dev in devs if dev.dob >= target_date]
```

As you can see there's no need for anything more in the Queryset api, but I doubt this will be much faster than querying the database unless you have a very small dataset or a very poor network connection between your django app and the database server (or any other infrastructure / database tuning issue).

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't support it, and I'm confused that you would ask why not.

Queries are done in the database. Doing what you ask would mean implementing an entire copy of that functionality in Python code, which would be inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: How would that be inefficient? Hitting cached results should be faster than hitting the db.

Comment: @dabadaba not necessarily, and even quite on the contrary for a lot of cases, unless you have a serious problem with your database and/or infrastructure. Databases are not mere bitbuckets, they are highly optimized querying engines and will most often outperform pure Python code.

Answer (score 0):

[When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

**Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.**

You can evaluate a QuerySet in the following ways:

Iteration. A QuerySet is iterable, and it executes its database query the first time you iterate over it. For example, this will print the headline of all entries in the database:

```
for e in Entry.objects.all():
    print(e.headline)
```

Note: Don’t use this if all you want to do is determine if at least one result exists. It’s more efficient to use exists().

Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.

Also note that even though slicing an unevaluated QuerySet returns another unevaluated QuerySet, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.

Pickling/Caching. See the following section for details of what is involved when pickling QuerySets. The important thing for the purposes of this section is that the results are read from the database.

> repr(). A QuerySet is evaluated when you call repr() on it. This is
>   for convenience in the Python interactive interpreter, so you can
>   immediately see your results when using the API interactively.
>
> len(). A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you
>   might expect, returns the length of the result list.

Note: If you only need to determine the number of records in the set (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s much more efficient to handle a count at the database level using SQL’s SELECT COUNT(*). Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason.

> list(). Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it. For
>   example:

```
entry_list = list(Entry.objects.all())
```

> bool(). Testing a QuerySet in a boolean context, such as using bool(),
>   or, and or an if statement, will cause the query to be executed. If
>   there is at least one result, the QuerySet is True, otherwise False.
>   For example:

```
if Entry.objects.filter(headline="Test"):
   print("There is at least one Entry with the headline Test")
```

Note: If you only want to determine if at least one result exists (and don’t need the actual objects), it’s more efficient to use exists().